# my sql of multiple conditions is not working

Tags: mysql, database

```
delete from tab_1 where lastname = "Ahmad" 
and INSERT INTO tab_1(firstname, lastname, title)VALUES("Kashif" , "Younis" , "I am working in GSK") 
AND update tab_1 set firstname = "Kh. Mohsin" WHERE id= 4;
```

Comment: someone please provide me with the best solution what should I do

Comment: You can't use an `INSERT` query in a `WHERE` condition. What do you intend with that?

Comment: Are you trying to execute this as a single query? Because these are 3 separate queries.

Comment: Multiple queries should be separated by `;`, not `AND`. If you're doing this from a programming language, do them as separate calls.

Comment: Barmar, I was trying to use all in one query

Answer (score 1):

You are using 'AND' in a context where it means something entirely different. You want to say "do this query and then to this query and then do another query", but that is not supported in the syntax of the language yo are using.

`AND` has a very specific meaning in a `WHERE` clause; you are creating a list of requirements that must be met. Putting the `AND` on a new line means nothing to MySQL.

I'm not sure how you are making this database request, but you have three distinct queries and you need to make them one at a time.